# Fix $n>0$. Is $\ln(x) \leq \sqrt[n]x$ for sufficiently large $x$?

Tags: calculus

I feel intuitively that $\ln(x) \leq \sqrt[n]x$ must be true, because the logarithm grows so slowly, but I'm not sure how to show it.

Comment: $\ln(8) = 2.07944154168 > 2 = \sqrt[3]8$

Comment: Clearly it isn't true for all $n$, because $\lim_{n\to\infty}x^n=1$ for all $x>0$, so just take any $x>e$. What you are probably asking is this: fix $n$, then is $\ln x\leq x^{1/n}$ for sufficiently large $x$? The answer to this is, YES.

Comment: Set $x=e^w$: is it true that $w\leq e^{w/n}$?

Comment: If I set $x = e^n$ then $(e^n)^{\frac{1}{n}} \leq ln(e^n)$ yields $e \leq n$ which is true since $n$ is not fixed and $e$ is.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not true. Look at the diagram below:[image]

If you take their derivatices, you get:

$\dfrac{d}{dx}ln(x) = \dfrac{1}{x} \\ \dfrac{1}{n * x^\dfrac{n-1}{n}}$

So if we want to compare these fractions, firstly I multiply both of them by $x$(knowing that x is a positive number since $\ln(x)$ for negative numbers is undefined)

$\dfrac{1}{x} \to 1 \\ \dfrac{1}{n*x^{\dfrac{n-1}{n}}} \to \dfrac{x^{\dfrac{1}{n}}}{n}$

For very large values of x, the latter derivative is obviously more that 1 which means that the blue function will get more than the red graph at some point.

Comment: For n>2 it is not correct.

Comment: You can check this here:https://www.desmos.com/calculator

Comment: So you mean that this inequality is correct for $x\to\infty$